# Meaning of "Like that of"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In "Heard in the next room, her voice is like that of a boy", so what is "like that of"?

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, the word *that* is a pronoun that stands for the word "voice".

> Heard in the next room, her voice is like the voice of a boy.